# Что делают знаки вопроса в коде

Tags: kotlin

Есть строка язык Kotlin

```
val currentindex = saveinstateState?.getInt(KEY_INDEX,0) ?: 0
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как работают эти два знака вопроса? знаю что это типа условия, но не пойму логики. Или подскажите где можно про них можно почитать. Я просто не знаю как такие условия называются.

Comment: [Вот это](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls) и [это](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin/null-safety#safe-calls) можно почитать.

Comment: Ссылка на оригинал [kotlinlang.org Safe calls](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#safe-calls)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov мне кажется вы можете оформить это как ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Знак вопроса перед вызовом свойства или метода (перед точкой) в Kotlin означает выполнение проверки на `null`. То есть код

```
val currentindex = saveinstateState?.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0)
```

Эквивалентен следующему:

```
val currentindex = if(saveinstateState == null || saveinstateState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0) == null) 
    null 
else saveinstateState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0)
```

Знак вопроса с двоеточием является элвис-оператором.

> Элвис-оператор сначала проверяет значение в левой части выражения. Если это значение отлично от null, Элвис-оператор возращает его, но если в левой части равно null, то возвращает то что в правой

Проще всего его понять на примере. Если взять Ваш код полностью (вместе с элвис оператором):

```
val currentindex = saveinstateState?.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0) ?: 0
```

То и эквивалентный код через if немного изменится:

```
val currentindex = if(saveinstateState == null || saveinstateState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0) == null) 
    0 // Вот здесь разница, без элвиса был бы null
else saveinstateState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0)
```

Просто забавный факт, позволяющий чуть легче запомнить название элвис-оператора:

> Название «Оператор Элвиса» относится к тому факту, что когда его обычное обозначение, `?:` , рассматривается сбоку, оно напоминает смайлик Элвиса Пресли с его специфической прической [quiff](https://wikichi.ru/wiki/Quiff)

Comment: Немного разобралась, но я бы написала проще. Элвис-оператор сначала проверяет значение в левой части выражения. Если это значение отлично от null, Элвис-оператор возращает его, но если в левой части равно null, то возвращает то что в правой.